# how i can send multivalue to create action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

i have a doctor i want add doctor subspecialty to the doctor from sub specialties table many to many relationship

i need to add subspecialties from multiselect list but my controller only add first selection , i want my create controller take all passed subspecialties and create it

my model

```
public partial class DoctorSubSpecialty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DoctorId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SubSpecialtyId { get; set; }

    public virtual DoctorProfile DoctorProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual  SubSpecialty SubSpecialty { get; set; }
}
```

}

create get action

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
            ViewBag.DoctorId = new SelectList(db.DoctorProfiles, "Id", "FullName");
            ViewBag.SubSpecialtyId = new MultiSelectList(db.SubSpecialties, "id", "Name");
            return View();
        }
```

create post action

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,DoctorId,SubSpecialtyId")] DoctorSubSpecialty doctorSubSpecialty)
    {

            DoctorSubSpecialty doctorSub = db.DoctorSubSpecialties.Where(d => d.DoctorId == doctorSubSpecialty.DoctorId & d.SubSpecialtyId == doctorSubSpecialty.SubSpecialtyId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (doctorSub == null) { 
            db.DoctorSubSpecialties.Add(doctorSubSpecialty);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>DoctorSubSpecialty</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoctorId, "DoctorId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @id = "DoctorID" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("DoctorId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoctorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubSpecialtyId, "SubSpecialtyId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("SubSpecialtyId",(MultiSelectList)ViewBag.SubSpecialtyId, htmlAttributes: new { @multiple = "multiple", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubSpecialtyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Create a **ViewModel** specific to your usecase that can actually transport more than one Id. 
I.e. you will need an `int[]` to bind the selection to.
A ViewModel also helps you to get rid of all this `ViewBag` and `[Bind]` nonsense.

```
public class CreateDoctorSubSpecialtyViewModel {

     // These are the selected values to be posted back
     public int DoctorId { get; set; }
     public int[] SubSpecialtyIds { get; set; }

     // These are the possible values for the dropdowns
     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DoctorProfiles { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SubSpecialties { get; set; }
}
```

GET action - initialize the ViewModel and pass it to the View:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create() {

    var doctorProfiles = db.DoctorProfiles.Select(d => 
        new SelectListItem {
            Text = d.FullName,
            Value = d.Id
        }
    ).ToArray();

    var subSpecialties = db.SubSpecialties.Select(s => 
        new SelectListItem {
            Text = s.Name,
            Value = s.id
        }
    ).ToArray();

    var viewModel = new CreateDoctorSubSpecialtyViewModel {
        DoctorProfiles = doctorProfiles,
        SubSpecialties = subSpecialties 
    };

    return View("Create", viewModel);
}
```

View "Create.cshtml" (styling removed for clarity) - tell MVC which ViewModel we want to use with `@model`:

```
@model CreateDoctorSubSpecialtyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post)) {

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DoctorId, Model.DoctorProfiles)

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SubSpecialtyIds, Model.SubSpecialties, new { multiple = "multiple" })

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

POST action - use Linq `Contains` to test against multiple submitted `SubSpecialtyIds`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CreateDoctorSubSpecialtyViewModel postData) {

    DoctorSubSpecialty[] allSelectedSubSpecialities = db.DoctorSubSpecialties
        .Where(d => d.DoctorId == postData.DoctorId 
                 && postData.SubSpecialtyIds.Contains(d.SubSpecialtyId)) 
        .ToArray();

    // ...
}
```

---

**EDIT** `@Html.DropDownListFor` requires an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as second parameter.